# what's the BTRFS equivalent of ZFS' ashift?

Tags: btrfs

as above.

I've searched the net and man and the only thing that seems similar is --sectorsize in mkfs.btrfs.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Different filesystems are *different*: exactly equivalent settings may or may not exist.

In ZFS, `ashift` determines the size of a *sector*, which is the smallest physical unit to read or write as a single operation. It is expressed as powers of two: `ashift=9` means sector size of 2^9 = 512 bytes, and `ashift=12` would be 2^12 = 4096 bytes. For optimum performance, the sector size determined by `ashift` should match (or be an exact multiple of) the physical block size of the disk (frequently either 512 or 4096 bytes on modern HDDs, but SSDs may use 8192 bytes or greater sizes).

If you're storing large numbers of small files, larger `ashift` may mean a relatively larger portion of disk capacity "wasted" as partially-filled blocks at the ends of files. Whether or not this is important enough to keep using `ashift=9` when the physical block size of the actual disks would instead call for using `ashift=12` or greater, depends on your actual use case (what you're storing and whether speed or space efficiency is more important).

---

BTRFS, on the other hand, *really* wants its `--sectorsize` to match the *memory page size* used by the system's processor(s). The `mkfs.btrfs(8)` man page says (emphasis mine):

> The default value is the page size and is autodetected. If the sectorsize differs from the page size, **the created filesystem may not be mountable by the kernel**. Therefore it is not recommended to use this option unless you are going to mount it on a system with the appropriate page size.

On x86 PC hardware, the standard page size is 4096 bytes, dictated by the processor hardware architecture. It has been so since year 1985 (when the first i386 processor was released) and not expected to change, as it would be a compatibility-breaking change at a very fundamental level.